# Typed DataSets with XML data sources and schemas

Tags: .net, xml, schema, dataset

I've written an XML Schema file by hand (not using the DataSet Designer in VS) and a corresponding XML file containing structured data to be read in.

I ran the xsd.exe program to generate a `Typed DataSet` class; on the whole it looks fine to begin with (ignoring how it uses lowercase for public class members), but when it comes to using the generated class nothing happens:

```
MyDataSet set = new MyDataSet();
set.ReadXml( "myData.xml" );
```

At this point all of the typed table members of the `MyDataSet` class have a `.Count` of 0.

Strangly enough, I can't get normal `DataSets` to work either:

```
DataSet set = new DataSet();
set.ReadXmlSchema("mySchema.xsd");
set.ReadXml( "myData.xml");
```

`set.Tables.Count` returns 7, which is right, but the tables are all empty.

Am I missing something obvious?

UPDATE:

After doing absolutely nothing `set.Tables["extra"].Rows.Count` returns the correct number of rows; but when I use a typed dataset it doesn't work, despite everything else being the same:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml( packageExamplePath );

System.Console.WriteLine( ds.Tables["extra"].Rows.Count );

Package st = new Package();
st.ReadXml( packageExamplePath );

System.Console.WriteLine( st.Tables["extra"].Rows.Count );
```

...prints this out to console:

> 19
>
> 0

Answer (score 0):

Question: is the code from xsd.exe being generated correctly? E.g., can you use the generated DS in code, create DataRows, add them to DataTables, etc?

If so, try filling the DS by hand, saving the xml, and comparing to your structured xml data file to make sure it has the same structure.